# Is it better to define your database schemas in SQL or with the application language?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, psql

I have 2 services running. One is a Node.js application, the other is a PSQL database. I am not sure where I should define my database schemas.

Some libraries like Sequelize define it with the application language (in that case javascript).

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'first_name' // Will result in an attribute that is firstName when user facing but first_name in the database
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});
```

But I thought it would be better to define them in pure SQL

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL,
  first_name varchar(85),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This way, other applications on other other platforms can use the database without screwing with the schemas. It seems to me, the database definition should be independent of the language of the application. Is there something I'm not considering? Why do so many libraries define your database schemas for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up databases and ORM (Object Relational Mapping) libraries. The database stores your data and therefore the schema always needs to be defined there. An ORM library helps you to map the objects of your application to the schema of the database. Many ORM libraries offer features for schema creation to make life easier, but under the hood they create a schema with SQL in the database like you could do yourself. 
Therefore you can use the database with other applications no matter what way you choose.